# Java cannot get one class inherit from another

Tags: java

Ok, I have 2 classes that need to inherit from another class..

When I move id fields over it says that it cannot access that fields as it is private. so I call the public get method... but it still doesnt work. What I need to do is move all field into vehicle and make taxi + shuttle to inherit from it

```
  public class Vehicle
{
    // A unique ID
    private String id;
    // The destination
    private String destination;
    // The location of this taxi.
    private String location;
        /**
     *Constructor for vehicle
     */
    public Vehicle(String id)
    {
        this.id=id;
    }
```

Comment: _but it still doesnt work_ What does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Vehicle
{
    // A unique ID
    private String id;
    // The destination
    private String destination;
    // The location of this taxi.
    private String location;

    /**
     *Constructor for vehicle
     */
    public Vehicle(String id)
    {
        this(id, null);
    }

    /**
     *Constructor for vehicle
     */
    public Vehicle(String id, String location)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.location = location;
    }

    /**
     * Returns ID.
     * 
     */
    public String getID()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public String getDesitnation() {
        return destination;
    }

    public void setDestination(String destination) {
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}

public class Taxi extends Vehicle   

    // Whether it is free or not.
    private boolean free;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Taxi.
     * @param base The name of the company's base.
     * @param id This taxi's unique id.
     */


    public Taxi(String base, String id)
    {
        super(id, base);
        free = true;
    }
}

public class Shuttle extends Vehicle
{
    // The circular route of this shuttle.
    private ArrayList<String> route;
    // The destination number in route that the shuttle is
    // currently headed for.
    private int destinationNumber;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Shuttle
     * @param id This shuttle's unique id.
     * @param route The route taken by this shuttle.
     *              The first entry is the starting location.
     */
    public Shuttle(String id, ArrayList<String> route)
    {
        super(id);
        this.route = route;
    }
}
```

Comment: I got another problem.. when i try and move the rest of the fields with this method i get errors.. i will edit the code so you see what i mean

Comment: As suggested before, can you please show what the errors are?  I can only see what you write, not what you see.

Comment: When i move destination over and write (String id, String Destination) {this.id=id; destination=destination;} it says that super(id) in taxi class cannot be applied to give type

Comment: I'll update my answer... although I would seriously check your parenthesis.  they're all wrong.  If you don't have each class in it's own file, I highly recommend you use a single class per file.  It will keep things simpler and clearer.

Comment: they are in different files dont worry :) i got 4 files.. taxiCo, Taxi, shuttle and vehicle

Comment: What i want to do is to move the id, destination and location into vehicle class and make shuttle and taxi to inherit from it

Comment: I've updated again to move destination and location to vehicle.  I'd also recommend reading this trail to get a better understanding of inheritance: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Answer (score 2):

Change the `Vehicle`'s constructor so that it takes an `int` argument, which you then assign to the classes `id` field

```
public Vehicle(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

Now, you'll be required to call `super(int )` in of your child classes, which will set the `id` field

```
    public Taxi(String base, String id){
        super(id);
        //...
    }
```

ps- I have no idea what this is trying to do, but it doesn't do anything...

```
    public void ID(){
        Vehicle id= new Vehicle();
        id.getID();
    }
```

And given the fact that we've changed the constructor, it will no lager compile...

Comment: It says constructor Vehicle in Vehicle class cannot be applied to this given type

Comment: Did you remove the old Vehicle constructor? Did you call super(id) inside Taxi?

Answer (score 1):

The attributes declared as `private` can not be accessed from a subclass. Either declare them as `protected` or create a constructor in the superclass that assigns them, and call that constructor from the subclass' constructor using `super()`.

Answer (score 0):

`When i move id fields over it says that it cannot access that fields as it is private.`
This word already tells you what restrict from inheritance.

In Java, every class can have totally `private` data in it, the key word `private` symbol the data that only this class can have, even you extends from it, those inherited class still can not use `private` field.

To utilize inheritance advances in Java but still do not want be accessed by class out of your package, you need to make it `protect` rather than `private` scope, hence those member fields would be inherited from base class.

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one problem here, here's what I can see as an issue with your code:

1) I'm assuming that both your code for Vehicle and Taxi are in separate class files. Multiple classes in one file can happen but is a bad practice.

2) id is not accessible for two reasons. The first is because you did not call super(). When extending a class, the first thing you have to do is call the super() class to grab all of the parent's variables. The second is because you've given it private access. Private means it is visible only to the Vehicle class. You can fix this two ways. The first is to change the [visibility](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_access_modifiers.htm) to something other than private. The second is to create [getter and setter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html) methods inside the Vehicle class that allow you to change id from other classes when using the setter.

3) The lines:

> location = base; destination = null; free = true;

What is location? What are base, destination, and free? These will also cause errors, you need to declare these variables first as instance variables before your constructor.

Hope this helps!